# How would I fix my python syntax highlighting in vscode?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Why do I see some of my "prev" and "next" not highlighted. I would also like to change the colors such as when using 'self' I would like to highlight that dark blue but sometimes my other ones are white.

I have tried disabling every installed extension I had and the problem still occurs. I just do not know what to do.

[image: VsCode Image]

Comment: Did you restart VSC or "reload window" through the command palette to make sure the extensions are disabled? If so, this is likely default highlighting, and an extension may help and should include directions for overriding the default syntax highlighting.

Comment: generally, if an identifier (i.e. a variable name, parameter name, or imported module name) appears greyed out, it's because you don't reference it anywhere after you initially define it, and VSCode is letting you know that it might not be necessary as you aren't actually using it.

Comment: `self` is not a keyword, it is colored as a variable, for the white colored parts use the TextMate Scope inspector to see what the scope of the colored part in front of the white are, and the scope of the white parts

Comment: please don't make us retype this to try to reproduce it. [mre]. keep the screenshot. add the code as text as well.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Include also your Python extension version and your Python interpreter version.

Comment: Based on the code shown, I think the issue is that it doesn't know if the attributes `curr.next`, `next.prev` or `prev.next` in the given cases exists, because it doesn't know what the type of `curr`, `next`, or `prev` is.  For example, in `addAtHead()`, it knows that `prev` is a `ListNode` and has a `next`, because `prev = self.left`, and it can get the type from the definition of `self`, but `next.prev` is the same as `self.left.next.prev`, and it can't figure out if that exists.  Try explicitly assigning types, such as `next: ListNode` and `curr: ListNode`